# Setting axes to logarithmic scale in ScatterMatrix plot in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, scatter-matrix

If I generate a figure as:

```
fig = px.scatter_matrix(df, dimensions=columns, color=coloring_column)
```

I wonder how can I set the x-axes or y-axes to the logarithmic scale.

The `fig.update_yaxes(type=scale)` method or the keyword `log_x` is not included in the `scatter_matrix` function differently from the scatter function.

Thank you

Comment: See this: [Axis range for log axis type](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#axis-range-for-log-axis-type)

Comment: @r-beginners log_x log_y are not valid keywords for scatter-matrix plots

Comment: I don't have a [sample](https://plotly.com/python/splom/#scatter-matrix-with-plotly-express) to put it in log format, so I was able to log the x-axis with the example in the reference, and I think a similar code could be used for the y-axis as well. `fig.update_layout(xaxis=dict(type='log'),xaxis2=dict(type='log'),xaxis3=dict(type='log'),xaxis4=dict(type='log'))`